# Quest rewards with a full inventory

Tags: borderlands-2

I've ended (cashed-in) quests with item/weapon rewards while I had a full inventory, and I couldn't tell what happened to the items. I don't think they made it to my inventory, but they weren't on the floor and there wasn't an option to close-out the quest again. Were the items liquidated into money, held on the side somewhere, or did they just disappear? What happens in this case?

Comment: Item drop in this game = throwing your item across the room.   Did you check 20+ feet in front of you? Or did it fall down a ledge ?

Comment: I would look for a minute or two near the quest bulletin boards before giving up each time. There's nowhere for them to be thrown. I'm thinking they're liquidated, but I wanted to confirm.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you have a full inventory, any quest rewards you get should still end up in your backpack. For example, if you have 15/15 backpack slots full and you get a SMG from a quest, your gun will be in your inventory and your backpack should display 16/15 capacity now.

Comment: Also, when you have a 29/27 inventory, you can put 2 items from your inventory into bank even if the bank is full.